# h2 database: avoid usage of backticks in queries in version 2.0.202

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, h2

I have just updated my com.h2database version 1.4.200 -> 2.0.202.
In previous version I could execute statements like this:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_SQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s (" +
        "name varchar(255) NOT NULL," +
        "value varchar(255) NOT NULL," +
        "PRIMARY KEY (name)" +
        ") ENGINE=InnoDB";
```

But newest version complains on:

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement

if I run it like this.

To fix syntax error I had to wrap all field names into backpacks like this:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_SQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s (" +
        "`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL," +
        "`value` varchar(255) NOT NULL," +
        "PRIMARY KEY (`name`)" +
        ") ENGINE=InnoDB";
```

I am using h2 for mySQL mode. My JDBC connect string looks like:

```
"jdbc:h2:mem:database;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=0;TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT=0;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;MODE=MySQL";
```

Is it possible to avoid usage of `` (backtick) symbols in every query against h2? And make queries compile without them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely `name` and/or `value` is a reserved keyword. There are hundreds, maybe thousands of such keywords. Just pick any other column name. Start trying namex and valuex just to check that's the problem, then think of a name that isn't a keyword.

Comment: yes! (sorry for previously removed comment). but why did it work okay with the previous version?

Comment: New reserved keywords are added all the time :(

Comment: sad story :( Thank you for your help!

Comment: Shouldn't there be a way to force downwards campatibility? Developers all over the world have to think about being using column names which are no keywords, and worse, that will not become keywords very soon? Column names they even did not choose by themselves? Somebody should raise an issue at H2.

Comment: @JBStonehenge There is a trivial solution: Shove all your identifiers (column names, table names, and so forth) in double quotes. The 'bug' is that almost all tutorials don't do it, thus, teaching you 'bad manners'. The flaw is in the tutorials, and no amount of bugs you file at the H2 project can fix that.